# Best way to combine the output of 2 neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, python, natural-language, ensemble-learning

I have 2 neural network models (pre-trained transformers BERT, but the input data (fine-tuning data) is different in each model) it's a binary classification task (1 or 0).

**Model 1** --> achieves an overall 45% F-measure (which is not that good of course)

**Model 2**---> achieves overall 80% F-measure (which is better).

However, most of the sentences which are wrongly classified in **model 2** (the 80% one) are correctly classified in **model 1** (although it achieves a low F-measure but it gets what model2 doesn't get).

What is the best way to combine the output of model1 and model2 ?
The output can either be 0 or 1, or we could look at the probability of each score [3.2,0.5] the former is the probability of 0 the latter is prob. of 1 (i.e: soft-max layer output).

What I did is soft-voting with the probability of each model output for each label as seen in the code below, but it only improved 1% so the F-measure is 81% instead of 80%, that why I want to check if there's a better way to go?

```
soft_voting=[]
import collections
for model1, model2 in zip(model_outputs,model_outputs2):
    
    prob_zero=max(model1[0],model2[0])
    prob_one=max(model1[1],model2[1])
    soft_voting_result=0 if prob_zero>prob_one else 1
    soft_voting.append(soft_voting_result)
```

I also tried replacing max with average or weighted average but didn't notice much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If the voting ensemble does not work out with the two models, you can either

- enlarge the ensemble (e.g. see [Risch/Krestel](https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/naumann/publications/PDFs/2020_risch_bagging.pdf) reporting "drastically increases when ensembling up to 15 BERT models")
- stack the two models by training a meta-model (e.g. see [Mohammed/Kora](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319157821003013) for more details and references in the context of text classification)